# Want to Mock ValidationofToken in restcontroller junit testing

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mocking, springmockito

Need to skip a Validation of token id login in controller for unit testing

Not sure what to use Mock or spy since i'm testing the controller itself

```
public class TestController extends BaseController {

    @Autowired
    TestService service;    

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public @ResponseBody TestResponse getAll(@RequestBody TestRequest request) {

        validateToken(request);
        TestResponse response = service.getall(request);
        response.setTokenID(request.getTokenID());
        return response;
    }   

}
```

---

```
public class BaseController {

    protected void validateToken(IRequest request) {

        TokenResponse tokenresponse = restTemplate.exchange(TokenServiceURL, HttpMethod.GET, null, TokenResponse .class, tokenId).getBody();
        User user = new user()
        user.setUserRole(tokenresponse.getUser()));
        request.setUser(user);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class TestControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
        private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Autowired
    private TestController testControlller;

    @MockBean
        private TestService testService;

    BaseController baseControllerSpy = Mockito.spy(BaseController.class);


    @Before
    public void setUp(){
         MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);        
             mockMvc =  MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    }


    @Test
    public void verifygetAll() throws Exception {
        TestRequest request = new TestRequest();        
        TestResponse response = new Response();     

        **Mockito.doNothing().when(baseControllerSpy).validateTokenID(request);**
        when(testService.get(request)).thenReturn(response);

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/test")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content(requestString)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
    }
```

### }

Base controller being spy doesn't seem to work, is there any other way i can approach this scenrio. please help

Answer (score 0):

I can advice you two solutions:

1. I assume that if you are in the same package then you have to inject a spy of TestController in the mockMvc when you do the build() then you can create the validateToken mockMvc

```
doNothing().when((BaseController)testController).validateTokenID(any());
```

2. If the previous solution is not compliant then you can extend the TestController class with the TestControllerForTest and you can make the override of the validateTokenID method where you do nothing.